# Cannot Replay Cached Video in IOS5 Safari with HTML5

Tags: html, caching, ios5, video

I'm working on a site using cached video in HTML5. It works fine on a laptop using Safari. When I test on mobile Safari using IOS 5, I see the following:

1. Site works and plays video fine when 1st loaded.
2. I get prompted if I want to cache 10 MB of data on my iPhone. I say yes. (Cache size in Safari was 9.5 MB) Website data page in mobile Safari settings confirms 9.5 MB are cached.
3. When I try to return to the website in a new tab, the HTML and images load, but for the video I get a play button with a line through it.

This happens regardless of whether I turn Airplane Mode on or off.

Answer (score 0):

I have the exact same issue. I have seen various things by searching that suggest one of two things. Either HTML5 cache.manifest doesn't allow video, or mp4/m4v videos get cached with a different name and then don't get found after caching. I'm hoping there is a way to do it, but I still haven't found anything.